# How to calculate facebook access_token using app_id and app_secret

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

I was wondering a way to let the functions calculate the `access_token` in **PHP** giving them the `app_id` and `app_secret`.

Is there a way or I have to calculate externally and past it as a value?

Comment: It's app_id|app_secret

Comment: i know i can use this formula, but i've seen it can be calculated in someway, the question it, how? or better, with what graph call ?

Comment: You mean make a request to Facebook?

Comment: yes, giving app_ip and app_secret in input

Answer (score 0):

Here from the [Facebook Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens):

> To generate an app access token, you need to make a Graph API call:

```
GET /oauth/access_token
?client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```